# how to collect the login information of all the clients who are connected to the server.this information should get from a directory in server

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dir = "D://Login.hhh";
    if (!File.Exists(dir))
    {
        File.Create(dir);
    }

    string filePath = dir;
    string s = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
    string s1 = getIP();
    using (StreamWriter swrObj = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        swrObj.Write(s1 + "|" + s + "|" + Txtusername.Text + "|" + "user logged in on :|" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        swrObj.Write("\t\t");
        swrObj.Write("\t\t");
        swrObj.WriteLine();
        MessageBox.Show("Login success");
    }
}

private void Loginform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

}
private string getIP()
{ 
    IPHostEntry host;
    string localIP = "?";
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
        {
            localIP = ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    return  localIP;
}
```

I am using the above coding for getting the login information of a single user,But I want to get the login information for mutiple users who are connected to the server and that information should be maintained in a directory which is located in server.
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new file every time a user logs in. Try to append data with every login event.
         File.Append(filename);
Also you can create a directory in project solution itself and add the  file there.

Comment: And you also dont need to check if file exists or not for File.Append

Comment: its k but i have one more doubt how u know what are all the systems connected to my server?and collect all users info?

Comment: What type of user information do you need can you be more specific?

Comment: yes,i created log files for users login info,insertion and deltion,update operations in project,i want collect all users login info,insertion log file,updation log file,at server machine,its possible,i am poor in communication,dnt esitate plz if u dint get my question?

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume based on your wording that this is a windows forms based application, and not a web application.

How secure does this have to be as it would be quite easy for the user to manipulate the data. Personally I would create a table on a database and log this information there. Ensure that your application only has write permission to this table and then you know the records haven't been altered.

Comment: can u explain one more thing?how we collects all informations frm client at server,is this possible,or its a wrong thinking?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of application you are writing, but if you have a server you are either talking directly to a database, or talking to the server via webservices - using either route would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: i am using windows application?